# Правильно истолковать законопроект

Tags: грамматика

Помогите пожалуйста правильно понять смысл нового законопроекта. Вот что там написано:
"предоставлять отсрочку:

- родителям (усыновителям) или опекунам (попечителям), осуществляющим уход за ребенком-инвалидом в возрасте до 18 лет или инвалидом с детства I группы.'
  Вопрос: фраза начинающаяся с " осуществляющим уход ", относится только к "опекунам (попечителям)", или полностью к "родителям (усыновителям) или опекунам (попечителям)"?
  Спасибо!

Comment: Союз ИЛИ означает равенство действия статьи на обе указанные категории.

Comment: Спасибо большое!